# Matrix -> Super Table - > Matrix

Tags: matrix, plugin-supertable

I have a matrix field with a Super Table block type. Then I have a matrix field as a field within the Super Table block. I am having trouble filtering by block type from within the child matrix field. Is what I am trying to achieve even possible? Any solution would save me from pulling my hair out any further.

Below is the last attempt I made to filter through before posting here:

```
{% for block in entry.matrixFieldParent %}

    {% if block.type == "superTableBlock" %}

        {% for row in superTableBlock %}

            {% for block in row.superTableBlock %}

                {% switch block.type %}

                    {% case "contentBlock1" %}

                       {{ block.contentField }}

                    {% case "contentBlock2" %}

                       {{ block.contentField }}

                {% endswitch %}

            {% endfor %}

        {% endfor %}

    {% endif %}

{% endfor %}
```

edited to include if statement previously left out by mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, you'll need to change:

`{% for row in superTableBlock %}` to `{% for row in block.superTableBlock %}`

So you can reference the Super Table field within your out Matrix field.

You also don't need to loop through `{% for block in row.superTableBlock %}`

I can't tell if you're looping through the inner Matrix field. Have you tried:

```
{% for block in entry.matrixFieldParent %}
    {% if block.type == "sectionBuilder" %}
        {% for row in block.sectionBlock %}
            {% for sectionLayout in row.sectionLayout %}
                {% switch sectionLayout.type %}
                    {% case "contentBlock" %}
                       {{ sectionLayout.sectionGrid }}
                    {% case "articlesFeedBlock" %}
                       {{ sectionLayout.sectionBackground }}
                {% endswitch %}
            {% endfor %}
        {% endfor %}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```